# In what geographical location are Firebase Authentication users stored?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Speaking of Firebase authentication only, for obvious reasons there is a case where **I'd like users database to be present only in EU and not to leave this region**. I know that during set up of a Firebase Project I get to choose Analytics and Cloud Firestore locations -

> **Analytics location** - This represents the country/region of your
>   organization, and sets the currency for revenue reporting. This does
>   not affect where Google may process and store Customer Data for
>   Firebase
>
> **Cloud Firestore location** - Defines where your Cloud Firestore data
>   resides and cannot be changed later, even if you don’t plan to use
>   Cloud Firestore at this time. This choice also sets the location of
>   your default Cloud Storage bucket, though you may create buckets in
>   other locations.

IMHO, none of this sheds a light on where exactly users database will be stored at. Or does it? If I select "europe-west3" as Firestore location, would it actually lead to users database residing there as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no way to specify where the Firebase Authentication data for your project is stored. For now you can only select a region for Analytics and Cloud Firestore.

Comment: It's a pity. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Isn't it especially relevant to know where the personal data of your users is stored? Would be awesome if this would be selectable, too!

Comment: is this still true in 2021? is there a way to select firebase authentication location?

Comment: Yes, this is still true today. The best you can do to make it clear you'd like to see this become something you can control is to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for valuable info. Do you know if there's any official document that states that? AFAIK they only say "[The Firebase Authentication service is run only from US data centers. As a result, Firebase Authentication processes data exclusively in the United States.](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#us-only_services)"