# Where are the Firebase server locations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am afraid of some latency when calling Firebase API. So I would like to know where the Firebase API servers are located. Are there any documents?   Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Firebase has 18+ products. Which specific product (and possibly API calls) are you asking about?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen
Thanks for your reply, we would like use Firebase Auth for now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800430/in-what-geographical-location-are-firebase-authentication-users-stored?

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation regarding choosing [locations for your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations), doesn't include an option for the Firebase Authentication. So currently, there is no way to specify a particular location for storing the Firebase Authentication data.

However, when you are using Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage, or Cloud Functions for Firebase, you're prompted to select your project's default location. On the other hand, when using the Realtime Database, you're prompted to select the location of the instance, and each instance can be in a [different location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795058/save-android-user-credentials-to-firebase-database-kotlin/).

If you are also using Analytics, you're also prompted to select an Analytics reporting location. You can select a country or region that represents the location of your organization.