# Firebase : store user data according to his country

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, region

I'm working on a project currently hosted on firebase. The authentication goes through Firebase Auth and we store user's data in Firestore.

For now, everything is hosted in EUR3 region. What if now I would like to host some users, like the one out of Europe, in another location (for their Auth data as well as the Firestore database being used). How could I achieve this ?

I cannot find any information about this in the firebase documentations...

Thanks in advance,
Vinny

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible.

For Authentication all data is currently stored globally.

Also see:

- [In what geographical location are Firebase Authentication users stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800430/in-what-geographical-location-are-firebase-authentication-users-stored)

For Firestore there is currently a limit of 1 database per project. You could create a separate project for each location where you want to store data of course, but that'd still leave you with the user data stored globally.